# Is depending on implicit conversion of 0 to nullptr_t a good idea?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

I have an assignment operator

```
auto& A::operator=(const std::nullptr_t) 
{
    // zero initialization
}
```

in order to allow the syntax `b=0`and  disallow `b=1`. What are the pitfalls of doing this, and what is a better way to do this which preserves the syntax `b=0`?

Comment: I would argue it's a bad design choice that might not be fully clear for readers of your code. Especially since you probably don't have an assignment operator which takes an integer as argument, or a non-explicit converting constructor taking an integer argument. I think it's better to be explicit with a `clear` function or similar.

Comment: It wont work with this: `A a, *p = nullptr;  a=p;` Also, note that an assignment is not an *"initialization"*.

Comment: .... But then why would anybody assign a pointer to an *non-pointer* object? I dont see any good use case to begin with.

Comment: @Nawaz I don't think the purpose here is to assign a pointer, it is simply to rely on the implicit conversion from `0` to `nullptr_t` to allow user to only assign `0`... But I don't see why anyone would want to do this?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. In my case A is a object like a matrix, tensor where "0" is well-defined  but other values are not obvious as to what they mean (apart from may be 1), and I feel it is a nice to have a b=0 instead of a b.clear() for the purpose.

Comment: `static A null();` method could be a better idea. Then you can use it in expressions `a = b * A::null();`, but your method does not allow that

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude no, I do not. A is like a matrix, so it initializes to 0 by default, and then it can change values in between.

Comment: Can you assign *other* values to the matrix like that? If not then it's not obvious why it should be possible just for `0`. That will make the code hard to understand and maintain. And if not very well documented users of your class will not remember that it's a special case, and try to use assignment using other values. It's always a good idea to avoid special cases. In short: No, I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: unique_ptr has `unique_ptr& operator=( nullptr_t ) noexcept;`, I think its more for legacy use when switching from raw pointers to smart pointers : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D

Comment: By the way, asking "is this a good idea or not" is very subjective, and as such I will vote to close the question as opinion-based.

Comment: Cool, static null methods it is. I was actually considering static methods because they allow me methods like Id() to get identity as well.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yeah, sure, my intent on asking was to make sure if I am missing something very obvious in form of an unexpected valid behavior.

Comment: With udl, you might have `A var = 0_a;` valid and `A var = 42_a;` not.